# Update dropdown menu based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I am creating a cinema Ruby on Rails application and am currently working on the bookings.

A user can select the amount of adult seats, child seats, student seats, and senior seats. A screen has many seats that are stored in the seats table but the user is not booking a specific seat but a quantity of seats. The drop down menus allow the user to select a maximum of 10 seats for each quantity (adult, child, student, senior) but if the screen has 50 seats and 45 of them are booked then the drop down menus are limited to a maximum of 5. But my problem is that this maximum is on each drop down - so a user could select 5 adult seats, child seats, student seats, and senior seats.

I know that I could add validation so that if a screen has 50 seats but 45 have already been booked and the user selects 5 adults, 5 children, 5 student, and 5 senior seats then it will add the quantities and existing bookings (5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + total existing bookings = 65) to ensure this is not over the screen's capacity. But what I want to do is make it so that the dropdown menus update based on the previous selection. So if there are a total of 5 seats left to book, and a user selects 3 adult seats the child, student, and senior dropdowns will be restricted to a maximum of 2.

Can someone please help me to do this. I have looked at so many links for dynamic drop downs but none of them address anything like this as they focus on things like countries and states.

views/bookings/_form.html.erb:

```
<td>
    <%= f.select :adult_seats, '0'..(@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats > 10 ? 10 : @booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats).to_s %><br>
</td>
<td>
    <%= f.select :child_seats, '0'..(@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats > 10 ? 10 : @booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats).to_s %><br>
</td>
<td>
    <%= f.select :senior_seats, '0'..(@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats > 10 ? 10 : @booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats).to_s %><br>
</td>
<td>
    <%= f.select :student_seats, '0'..(@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats > 10 ? 10 : @booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats).to_s %><br>
</td>
```

Screen.rb:

```
 class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :seats
 has_many :showings
 has_many :bookings, through: :showings

def remaining_seats
  available_seats = seats.count - bookings.sum(:adult_seats)
  available_seats = available_seats - bookings.sum(:child_seats)
  available_seats = available_seats - bookings.sum(:disabled_seats)
  available_seats = available_seats - bookings.sum(:student_seats)
  available_seats = available_seats - bookings.sum(:senior_seats)
  available_seats = available_seats - bookings.sum(:immortal_seats)
end
end
```

Schema.rb:

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "showing_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  t.integer  "adult_seats"
  t.integer  "child_seats"
  t.integer  "senior_seats"
  t.integer  "student_seats"
end

create_table "screens", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "seats", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "row_letter"
  t.integer  "row_number"
  t.integer  "screen_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "showings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date     "show_date"
  t.time     "show_time"
  t.integer  "film_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "screen_id"
end
```

Comment: You need to have a total remaining seats var client side, then limit subsequent dropdowns based on the selection. Ideally this would do a call to the server to check they are still available or lock the booking from other people.

Comment: Ok, so how can I do that? There isn't a need to lock the booking form for other people as the system will only ever be accessed by one person at a time.

Comment: I'm working on a sample for you.

Comment: Thanks, have you got anything working?

Comment: Ha, i spend an hour doing the logic on this and dude disappears.

Comment: Sorry different timezone, I implemented your code, checked my page source and the drop down menus display the HTML code that is pretty much the same as yours, and I've got the `input type="hidden"` working. But it still isn't working, your example as well doesn't work as the second dropdown does not update based on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/zdzfsq7m/4/

I'd recommend returning the total number that are available in an input field, instead of the number that are taken.

```
<input type="hidden" value="8" name="seats_available" id="seats_available">
<select id="adult" name="adult">
    <option val="0">0</option>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    <option val="5">5</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<select id="child" name="child">
    <option val="0">0</option>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    <option val="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var seats_available = parseInt($('#seats_available').val());
    var max_allowed = 5;

    $('select').on('change', function () {
        var currently_selected = 0;
        $('select').each(function() {
            currently_selected += parseInt($(this).val());            
        })
        $('select').each(function () {
            var nowAvailable = seats_available - currently_selected;
            var currentlySelectedValue = parseInt($(this).val());           
            $(this).find('option').each(function () {
                $option = $(this)           
                num = parseInt($option.val());
                if (num <= currentlySelectedValue)
                    $option.prop('disabled', false);
                else if (nowAvailable >= 5)
                    $option.prop('disabled', false);
                else
                    $option.prop('disabled', num - currentlySelectedValue >= nowAvailable);               
            })
        });
    })    

})
```

Comment: Thanks, you've provided HTML but how would I use the Rails `f.select` that I am currently using?

Comment: you're going to have to look at the HTML that rails renders and then write the javascript.... rails won't help you here my friend. Just look at the html it puts out and write the javascript for it.

Comment: But this answer is very close to the exact javascript code you need to get get it working. Just copy and paste it below jquery on your page and adjust the element selectors as needed.

Comment: I'm just not sure how the HTML would work and how I'd hide the input type

Comment: I can't spoon feed you the entirety of how to do this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field    Render the number of seats left in a hidden field, copy and paste the javascript into your page (after jquery) and then play with it.